# Failing to delete dictionaries that contain a string 'False' as value

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have a list with sublists that contain dictionaries:

```
[[{'a': 'False'}, {'a': 'True'}], 
 [{'b': 'False'}, {'b': 'True'}],
 [{'a': 'False', 'b': 'False'}, {'a': 'False', 'b': 'True'},
  {'a': 'True', 'b': 'False'}, {'a': 'True', 'b': 'True'}]]
```

My goal is to delete all dictionaries that contain the string 'True'.
I tried it like this:

```
for comb in combination:
    for my_dict in comb:
        if 'False' in my_dict.values():
            comb.remove(my_dict)
```

However, the output I get is this

```
[[{'a': 'True'}], [{'b': 'True'}], [{'a': 'False', 'b': 'True'}, {'a': 'True', 'b': 'True'}]]
```

Can anybody tell me why this isn't working correctly? I thought at first it might be that python only looks at the first value (which wouldn't make sense, I know) and decides that the value is not 'False', but that doesn't seem the case. My for loop also fails to recognize dictionaries where the first value is 'False'. I'm wondering if there might be a problem with the strings being 'True' and 'False'? Could somebody maybe help out? I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a copy of my sublists `comb`. Apparently, I already deleted elements that I still needed to iterate over. So the solution to this would be

```
for comb in combination:
    for my_dict in comb.copy():
        if 'False' in my_dict.values():
            comb.remove(my_dict)
```

Now all 'False' strings are removed.